# Get only valid url from a file in Python

Tags: python

could someone help me please? I have an output.txt file (example file) which looks like this:

## output.txt:

```
account.netflix.com
prod.netflix.com
netflix.com
https://google.com
```

and I’m trying to put in a file alive.txt just only the existing url with this code

```
import socket

with open("output.txt", 'r') as f:
    for url in f:
        try:
            addr1 = socket.gethostbyname(url)
            print(addr1 + " is a valid url")

            f = open("alive.txt", "a")
            f.write("\n" + addr1)
            f.close()

        except:
            print("not valid")

f.close()
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you tried to check if it's valid url and if yes write to file ?

Comment: can you try my answer ? i´ve updated :)

Comment: I suggest you to use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you read the url from the file. When you read the url in `url` variable, it has an endling `\n` newline character with it. You have to remove this and then use the url.

Replace this line:

```
addr1 = socket.gethostbyname(url)
```

with this one:

```
addr1 = socket.gethostbyname(url.rstrip())
```

Moreover, I think you are not aware of python that much, as your code has various things that needs correction.

1. You have two file references with same name `f`. Don't do this, it will lead to some strange behavior.
2. You are opening the file again and again in `for-loop`, it's not pythonic. Just open the file once, and when the task ends, close the file.
3. Using `with` to open the file you don't have to close the file later on. `with` is just for this purpose so, that there is no need to close the file.

You can check given code for above mentioned points.

```py
import socket

with open("test.txt", 'r') as in_file, open("alive.txt", "a") as out_file :
    for url in in_file:
        try:
            addr1 = socket.gethostbyname(url.rstrip())
            print(addr1 + " is a valid url")
            out_file.write("\n" + addr1)
        except:
            print("not valid")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it helps me a lot. And yes, I have started with Python one week ago... :)

Comment: Glad to help, If it helps never forget to give a upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try changing the order of your functions :

```py
import socket

f = open("alive.txt", "w")
with open("output.txt") as fp:
    line = fp.readline()

    while line:
        try:
            clean_line = line.strip()
            addr1 = socket.gethostbyname(clean_line)
            print("valid url : " + addr1 + " from " + clean_line)
            f.write(addr1 + "\n")

        except:
            print("not valid: " +addr1 + " from " + clean_line)

        line = fp.readline()

f.close()
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for you help! this was exactly what I needed. :)
I just replace the write part instead of addr1 I added clean_line

Comment: Glad to help :)